# Canvas HTML5 rendering on Safari - strange results compared with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have an issue concerning a canvas HTML5, especially its rendering in Safari. This rendering is good on Firefox and Chrome but not with Safari.

Here's a capture of this canvas on Firefox :

[image: Capture with Firefox]

and the capture with Safari :

[image: Capture with Safari]

As you can see, there's an issue with Safari : the left menu (masses, initial positions, initial speeds) is flattened (see the 3 parameters lines compressed).

I don't know where this issue could come from. You can check this rendering on [this link](http://beulu.com/last/issue_safari/).

Here's the part of code which represents this HTML5 canvas :

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:750px;">
         <table> 
         <tr>
         <td colspan="3">
         <div class="col-md-12"> 
           <label for="slider"><b>Axis lengths</b></label>
             <br>
             <input id="slider1" type="hidden" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="4.8" data-slider-max="235.2" data-slider-step="4.8" data-slider-value="[81.6,158.4]" /> 
            </div>
         </td>
         <td rowspan="5">
<canvas id="pendulumCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;">
</canvas>
     </td>
         </tr>
     <tr>
           <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab1" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{M_{1}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab1" tabindex="1"/>
            </td>
              <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab2" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{M_{2}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab2" tabindex="2"/>
            </td>
      <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab3" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{M_{3}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab3" tabindex="3"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
     <tr>
           <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab4" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{\Theta_{1}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab4" tabindex="4"/>
            </td>
              <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab5" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{\Theta_{2}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab5" tabindex="5"/>
            </td>
      <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab6" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{\Theta_{3}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab6" tabindex="6"/>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab7" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{\dot{\Theta}_{1}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab7" tabindex="7"/>
            </td>
              <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab8" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{\dot{\Theta}_{2}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab8" tabindex="8"/>
            </td>
      <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab9" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{\dot{\Theta}_{3}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab9" tabindex="9"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab3" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{K_{1}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab10" tabindex="10"/>
            </td>
      <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab3" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{K_{2}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab11" tabindex="11"/>
            </td>
      <td class="col-md-4">
            <label for="lab3" tabindex="-1"><b>$\mathbf{K_{3}}$</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab12" tabindex="12"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
     <div class="center">
         <button type="button" id="startButtonId" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="13">Start</button>
         <button type="button" id="resetButtonId" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="14">Reset</button>
     </div>     
         </td>
         </tr>
            </table>
      </div>

<br><br>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/triple_pendulum.js">
</script>
</td>
```

If someone could give me some clues to solve this strange rendering on Safari.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing a difference because of the way that extra space is distributed between table cells in the various browsers.  In the current version of Safari each cell is only taking up as much space as it needs.  This leaves a bunch of extra space left over on the last cell.  The code below demonstrates this.

```css
#canvas, #cell-1, #cell-2 {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#canvas {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 100px;
}

#cell-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#cell-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell-1">CELL 1</td>
      <td id="canvas" rowspan="2">CANVAS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell-2">CELL 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There are many solutions to this problem.  You could try adding some padding to the td elements as shown below.

```css
#canvas, #cell-1, #cell-2 {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#canvas {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 100px;
}

#cell-1, #cell-2 {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

#cell-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#cell-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell-1">CELL 1</td>
      <td id="canvas" rowspan="2">CANVAS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell-2">CELL 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A better solution may be to take a look at your use of tables and how you might accomplish a similar result using CSS and positioning or even [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).